# Can't get selective names connected to a certain tab in a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python using requests module and BeautifulSoup library to get the name of different persons under this title `Browse Our Offices` from a website. The thing is when I run my script then it get random names which have been populated automatically, meaning without selecting any tab.

[Website Link](https://www.schooleymitchell.com/offices/)

When visiting that page you can see that those tabs are like the image below:

[image]

I would like to make the selection like the image below. To be clearer - I wanna select the `United states` tab and then select each of the `states` to parse the names connected to them. That's it.

[image]

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.schooleymitchell.com/offices/"

res = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for item in soup.select("#consultant_info > strong"):
    print(item.text)
```

The above script produces random names but I wish to get the names connected to `United States` tab.

***How can I get all the names populated upon selecting `United States` and it's different `states` tabs without using selenium?***

Comment: Do you need names associated with any other info or simply all the names from united states all states in one list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important data is in `<div>` tag with `id="office_box"`. You are interested only with consultants that are inside `<div>` that ends with `-usa`. First column contains name, second city and state:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.schooleymitchell.com/offices/'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')


for div in soup.select('#office_box div[id*="-usa"] div.consultant_info_container'):
    for a in div.select('a'):
        a.extract()
    info = div.get_text(separator=" ").strip()
    info = re.split(r'\s{2}', info)
    for data in info:
        print('{: ^45}'.format(data), end='|')
    print()
```

Prints:

```
        Steven Bremer                |              Gadsden, Alabama               |             Voice: 256-328-2485             |
        David George                 |             Montgomery, Alabama             |             Voice: 334-649-7535             |
  Zachary G. Madrigal, MBA           |              Phoenix, Arizona               |             Voice: 602-677-7804             |
   Richard E. Perraut Jr.            |              Phoenix, Arizona               |             Voice: 480-659-3831             |
     Stephen Moore B.A.              |             Scottsdale, Arizona             | Voice: 480-354-3423 Toll-Free: 866-213-5141 |
       Danny Caballes                |               Tempe, Arizona                |             Voice: 480-592-0776             |
         Brian Lutz                  |               Tucson, Arizona               | Voice: 520-447-7921 Toll-Free: 888-633-1451 |
       Travis McElroy                |           Bakersfield, California           |             Voice: 800-361-4578             |
        Matt Denburg                 |          Orange County, California          | Affiliated Office | Bottomline Consulting Group, Inc.|             Voice: 714-482-6025             |
       Pete Craigmile                |            San Diego, California            |                   Voice:                    |
         Greg Lowry                  |          San Francisco, California          | Affiliated Office | DBA Lowry Telecom Consultant|          Voice: 415-692-0708 Ext 1          |
       Dave Tankersley               |         Colorado Springs, Colorado          |             Voice: 719-266-1098             |
        Sanjay Tyagi                 |              Denver, Colorado               |             Voice: 303-317-3110             |
         Richard Ray                 |          Highlands Ranch, Colorado          |             Voice: 303-306-8568             |
       Richard Norlin                |          Highlands Ranch, Colorado          |             Voice: 612-309-5451             |
       Dave Dellacato                |           Bridgeport, Connecticut           |             Voice: 203-442-1311             |
      Patrick Delehanty              |           Brookfield, Connecticut           |             Voice: 475-289-2325             |
          Greg Wisz                  |        Fairfield County, Connecticut        |             Voice: 616-884-0058             |
       Jack McCullough               |        Fairfield County, Connecticut        |             Voice: 203-767-5551             |
      Matthew McCarthy               |            Hartford, Connecticut            |             Voice: 203-304-9886             |
   Paul Nelson BS CHE, MBA           |            Hartford, Connecticut            |             Voice: 860-926-4260             |

...and so on.
```

Answer (score 1):

First scrape all people, then filter them using their `id`s which is formatted like `{city}-{state}-{country}`. One problem is that spaces in multi-word state/city names are replaced with dashes `-`. But we can handle it easily by creating a lookup table using the state list on the left sidebar.

Here's how:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def make_soup(url: str) -> BeautifulSoup:
    res = requests.get(url, headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'
    })
    res.raise_for_status()
    return BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')


def extract_people(soup: BeautifulSoup) -> list:
    people = []
    state_ids = {s['id']: s.text.strip()
                 for s in soup.select('#state-usa .state')}
    for person in soup.select('#office_box .office'):
        person_id = person['id']
        location, country = person['id'].rsplit('-', 1)
        if country != 'usa':
            continue

        state, city = None, None
        for k in state_ids.keys():
            if k in location:
                state = state_ids[k]
                city = location.replace(k, '').replace('-', ' ').strip()
                break

        name = person.select_one('#consultant_info > strong').text.strip()
        contact_url = person.select_one('.contact-button')['href']
        p = {
            'name': name,
            'state': state,
            'city': city,
            'contact_url': contact_url,
        }
        people.append(p)
    return people


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'https://www.schooleymitchell.com/offices/'
    soup = make_soup(url)
    people = extract_people(soup)

    print(people)
```

output:

```
[
    {'name': 'Steven Bremer', 'state': 'Alabama', 'city': 'Gadsden', 'contact_url': 'https://www.schooleymitchell.com/sbremer/contact'}, 
    {'name': 'David George', 'state': 'Alabama', 'city': 'Montgomery', 'contact_url': 'https://www.schooleymitchell.com/dgeorge/contact'}, 
    {'name': 'Zachary G. Madrigal, MBA', 'state': 'Arizona', 'city': 'Phoenix', 'contact_url': 'https://www.schooleymitchell.com/zmadrigal/contact'}, 
    ...
]
```